# how to pick with an optionmenu the input for a function

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

i need to know how to choose with an option-menu the input for a function `FindIndex` which i activate with a button. i tried with

```
opt1 = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable1,*OptionList)
button1 = tk.Button(master=root, text='Bestätige', command=FindIndex4(variable1.get()))
```

but it doesn't work

below is the whole code. you cannot run it because you need an Excel data named `Ausgangsdaten.xlsx`

thank you a lot

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

dp_ts_SpaltenIndex={}
SpaltenNumSort1={}   # Spalte von Drehzahl n 
SpaltenNumSort2={}   # Spalte von Volumenstrom V_Dot
deta_ts_SpaltenIndex={}

df = pd.read_excel("Ausgangsdaten.xlsx")
SpaltenListe=df.columns.tolist()

def FindIndex1(Suche):
    global SpaltenListe
    global SpaltenNumSort1
    matched_indexes = []
    i = 0
    length = len(SpaltenListe)
    while i < length:
         if Suche == SpaltenListe[i]:
            matched_indexes.append(i)
         i += 1
    SpaltenNumSort1= matched_indexes

def FindIndex2(Suche):
    global SpaltenListe
    global SpaltenNumSort2
    matched_indexes = []
    i = 0
    length = len(SpaltenListe)
    while i < length:
         if Suche == SpaltenListe[i]:
            matched_indexes.append(i)
         i += 1
    SpaltenNumSort2= matched_indexes

def FindIndex3(Suche):
    global SpaltenListe
    global dp_ts_SpaltenIndex
    matched_indexes = []
    i = 0
    length = len(SpaltenListe)
    while i < length:
         if Suche == SpaltenListe[i]:
            matched_indexes.append(i)
         i += 1
    dp_ts_SpaltenIndex= matched_indexes

def FindIndex4(Suche):
    global SpaltenListe
    global deta_ts_SpaltenIndex
    matched_indexes = []
    i = 0
    length = len(SpaltenListe)
    while i < length:
         if Suche == SpaltenListe[i]:
            matched_indexes.append(i)
         i += 1
    deta_ts_SpaltenIndex= matched_indexes
    

 
root=Tk()
root.title('Spaltenauswahl')  
OptionList = SpaltenListe
variable1 = tk.StringVar(root) 
variable2 = tk.StringVar(root)
variable3 = tk.StringVar(root)
variable4 = tk.StringVar(root)
variable1.set('Wähle aus')
variable2.set('Wähle aus')
variable3.set('Wähle aus')
variable4.set('Wähle aus')
w1 = Label(root, text="Drehzahl:")
w2 = Label(root, text="Volumenstrom:")
w3 = Label(root, text="Druckänderung:")
w4 = Label(root, text="Wirkungsgradänderung:")
opt1 = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable1,*OptionList)
opt2 = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable2,*OptionList) 
opt3 = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable3,*OptionList)
opt4 = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable4,*OptionList)
button1 = tk.Button(master=root, text='Bestätige', command=FindIndex1(variable1.get()))
button2 = tk.Button(master=root, text='Bestätige', command=FindIndex2(variable2.get()))
button3 = tk.Button(master=root, text='Bestätige', command=FindIndex3(variable3.get()))
button4 = tk.Button(master=root, text='Bestätige', command=FindIndex4(variable4.get()))
w1.pack()
opt1.pack()
button1.pack()
w2.pack()
opt2.pack()
button2.pack()
w3.pack()
opt3.pack()
button3.pack()
w4.pack()
opt4.pack()
button4.pack()

root.geometry("500x600")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Also, your button command should be `command=lambda: FindIndex4(variable1.get())`